# how to run a plugin in Ckeditor without click

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to run a ckeditor plugin "showblocks" with several different approaches from question and answer but nothing work. Does anyone know how to run a plugin without click?

```
CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(199, this);
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].execCommand('show blocks');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the command is "showblocks", not "show blocks" (there is no space between the words).

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].execCommand('showblocks');
```

EDIT: After reading your comments, you are trying to execute showblocks automatically when ckeditor loads, but you can't do that until ckeditor fully loads and is ready for interaction. Also, the configuration option is called startupOutlineBlocks. You have 3 options.

First option (enable showblocks globally using [startupOutlineBlocks](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-startupOutlineBlocks) ):

```
CKEDITOR.config.startupOutlineBlocks = true;
```

Second option (enable showblocks for specific instance):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    startupOutlineBlocks: true
});
```

Third option (execute showblocks command after ckeditor fully loads using [instanceReady](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-instanceReady) event ):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function(evt) {
            this.execCommand('showblocks');
        }
    }
});
```

You don't need third option if you have enabled first or second option which are better anyway.

Comment: I did this once too, but false

Comment: It's working for me. Please share your code to examine further.

Comment: what version, are you using. I use CKEditor 4 Copyright (c) 2003-2017

Comment: My version is 4.11.1. Are you seeing the showblocks icon in the toolbar? The showblocks plugin is installed by default only in the full mode.

Comment: yes, it has, I can run showblocks by click on the icon.

Comment: Well, I can't help you any more, if you don't show more code.

Comment: Here it is but i think it has nothing to show
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    });
         
   
    CKEDITOR.config.showBlock = true;

    CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].execCommand('showblocks');

Comment: So, you just need it automatically enabled when ckeditor loads?

Comment: You should have said that in the first place. I have updated my answer for your problem.